# Tomcat Не открывает index.xhtml

Tags: xml, tomcat, jsf

При попытке запустить на Tomcat страницу пишет ошибку 404 с сообщением:
"The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."
Структура файлов:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
          xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>

    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>toMain</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>main.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>

</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>main.xhtml</from-view-id>

    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>toIndex</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>

</navigation-rule>
```

Что не так?

Comment: Что в логах Tomcat? Есть ошибки? И что у тебя в `.war`?

Comment: все,исправилось.